# debuild cannot remove '..' permission denied, debian/rules:9: recipe for target 'clean' failed

Tags: debian, makefile

I am trying to run debuild command to work with debian with my project However, when I run debuild command I get such error:

```
hoseopjeong@hoseopjeong-VirtualBox:~/Documents/HoseopJeong_debian_lab9/debianlaboration9-0.0$ debuild
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package debianlaboration9
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.0-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution UNRELEASED
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Ho Seop Jeong <my email>
dpkg-source --before-build debianlaboration9-0.0
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture i386
fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean  
 dh_testdir
 dh_auto_clean
  make -j1 distclean
 make[1]: Entering directory 
'/home/hoseopjeong/Documents/HoseopJeong_debian_lab9/debianlaboration9-0.0'
rm -f electrotest
make[1]: Leaving directory 
'/home/hoseopjeong/Documents/HoseopJeong_debian_lab9/debianlaboration9-0.0'
dh_clean
rm -f debian/debhelper-build-stamp
rm -f debian/debianlaboration9.substvars
rm -f debian/debianlaboration9.*.debhelper
rm -rf debian/debianlaboration9/
rm: cannot remove 'debian/debianlaboration9/usr/electrotest_standalone': Permission denied
 dh_clean: rm -rf debian/debianlaboration9/ returned exit code 1
 debian/rules:9: recipe for target 'clean' failed
 make: *** [clean] Error 25
 dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
 debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

this is how my makefile look like:

```
prefix = /usr/local
all: electrotest
electrotest: ./src/electrotest_standalone.c
   gcc -o electrotest_standalone ./src/electrotest_standalone.c -lm
install:electrotest
   install -D electrotest_standalone \
$(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/bin/electrotest_standalone
clean:
   -rm -f electrotest
distclean:clean
uninstall:
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/bin/electrotest_standalone
PHONY: all install clean distclean uninstall
```

this is my debian rules file

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# You must remove unused comment lines for the released package.
export DH_VERBOSE = 1
export DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS = hardening=+all
export DEB_CFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND  = -Wall -pedantic
export DEB_LDFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND = -Wl,--as-needed

%:
    dh $@  

#override_dh_auto_install:
#   dh_auto_install -- prefix=/usr

#override_dh_install:
#   dh_install --list-missing -X.pyc -X.pyo
override_dh_auto_install:
    dh_auto_install -- prefix=/usr
```

So as you see errors generated in terminal, If I understand right, debuild somehow tries to run clean that is defined in makefile to remove elecrotest which is created inside debian folder. However the folder is a folder with a limited privilege and clean shows permission denied error.

I have checked this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304590/how-to-prevent-debuild-from-performing-a-clean How to prevent debuild from performing a clean? and one of the answers are saying

```
override_dh_clean:
```

but I was not sure is that a right way to go because I thought it can make problems with build. Is changing privilege of folder generated by debian with chmod a the only way to go? or is there any smart idea that can solve this problem? I am not looking for workarounds.. need some solution to this

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; and only mention Debian.  Ubuntu does use debian packaging so many of your references are explained, but what OS/release are you using?  Are you on-topic?  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  As nothing you mention so far has made it so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [debmake FileNotFound error on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413913/debmake-filenotfound-error-on-ubuntu-16-04-6-lts)

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm